# Localize with values from Dictionary of enums and strings in XAML

Tags: xaml, data-binding, xamarin.forms

**I´m trying to databind the current culture with the right enum set in a Dictionary in Xamarin Forms XAML.**

I get a list of Events from the server that contain the Dictionary properties containing the languages that I´m going to use to show the right language depending on what Culture is set.

```
public class Event 
{
  // Having problem binding with the right CultureInfo í the Dictionary
  public Dictionary<Language, string> Title { get; set; }
}

// Types of languages that I could use to pick the right language string
public enum Language
{
    English = 0,
    German
}

// Just a basic view-model
public class EventsViewModel 
{
   public EventsViewModel()
   {
   }

    //James Montemagno´s MVVM Helper https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers
    public ObservableRangeCollection<Event> Events { get; } = new ObservableRangeCollection<Event>();
}
```

// Just a basic Content page
    public partial class EventsPage : ContentPage
    {
        public EventsPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new EventsViewModel(Navigation);
        }
    }

**Now I just need the XAML to bind the right value in the Dictionary based on the enum/culture**...

I have tried doing this "semi-manual" by using a Converter and checking the CultureInfo and picking the right value **but for some reason I just can´t get the Converters to fire up.**

I also tried to mix up IValueConverter and IMarkupExtension but no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out what was missing from the Converter method I had been trying to use. **I was missing the ConvertParameter** and that was the reason the Convert method did´t fire.

So what I did.

**1.**

I put this line into the App.xaml to be able to access it from anywhere

```
 <converters:LanguageDictionaryEnumConverter x:Key="LanguageConverter" />
```

**2.**

Then I put this one into my page. **I do not use the parameter at all.** (B*ut I would if I could pass in my settings culture object*)

```
<Label Text="{Binding Title,Converter={StaticResource LanguageConverter},ConverterParameter={x:Static dataObjects:Language.English}}" />
```

**3.**

And then I implemented a crude dictionary-language-enum converter/picker that chooses the right language string to send back to the page.

```
    public class LanguageDictionaryEnumConverter : IMarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dic = (Dictionary<Language, string>)value;

        var cultInMySettings= Settings.Current.GetCultureInfoOrDefault;
        switch (cultInMySettings.Name)
        {
            case "de-DE":
                return dic[Language.German];
            case "en-US":
                return dic[Language.English];
            default:
                return dic[Language.English]; 
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

**But if you have some better way to databind the values straight to the XAML in some other way I want to hear about it** a*nd will choose that answer over this one for sure if its more elegant.*